# IE6 Overflow Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
<div style="float:left; width:50%;">
    div 1
    <div style="position:absolute; width:105%">nested element</div>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:50%;">
    div 2
</div
```

If an element exceeds the width of its floated parent element, the next element is pushed down unless I apply `overflow:hidden` on both floated elements, which defeats the purpose because I DO NOT want to hide the overflowing content. Is there any fix for it?

Comment: Tell us a bit more about what you are trying to achieve so we can suggest alternatives.. Floated elements will always wrap when they fill their containers witdth. It is what they are designed for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure the content inside is not wider than the divs to stop the elements being pushed down in this scenario.

You could perhaps put `margin-right: -5%` on the positioned div to make it's width narrower in the document flow, but it should still display at 105% wide once rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to 100%, not 105% - otherwise, it is simply doing what you told it to do.

Comment: Wepp, sometimes the child elements are larger like if I wanted to apply a shadow etc..This is a problem only in IE6, no other browsers.